# Table with details in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I've got tabular data loaded in AngularJS app. I want to display them in a table. But I also want to have detail view for some rows. Something like:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="datum in data">
        <!-- if datum.showDetail => detail view -->

            <td colspan="N">
                <h1>{{ datum.field1 }} <small>{{ datum.field2 }}</small></h1>
                ...
                <p>{{ datum.fieldN }}</p>
            </td>

        <!-- else => row view -->

            <td>{{ datum.field1 }}</td>
            <td>{{ datum.field2 }}</td>
            ...
            <td>{{ datum.fieldN }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

What's the Angular way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just adding `ng-show` and `ng-hide` directives to the td's?

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="datum in data" >
        <!-- if datum.showDetail => detail view -->

            <td colspan="N" ng-show="datum.showDetail">
                <h1>{{ datum.field1 }} <small>{{ datum.field2 }}</small></h1>
                ...
                <p>{{ datum.fieldN }}</p>
            </td>

        <!-- else => row view -->

            <td ng-hide="datum.showDetail">{{ datum.field1 }}</td>
            <td ng-hide="datum.showDetail">{{ datum.field2 }}</td>
            ...
            <td ng-hide="datum.showDetail">{{ datum.fieldN }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Also note that, in case you're using the Angular UI extensions, the `ui-if` directive would probably be a better fit, since it would actually remove the unused td's from the table, instead of just hiding them, like `ng-hide`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out ui-if directive. That is exactly what I need.

Comment: as of Angular 1.1.4 `ui-if` is now included in the core as `ng-if`